# Fluent NHibernate not working with deployed application but works in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, development-environment, setup-project

A project i'm working on at my work is using Fluent Nhibernate and NHibernate to connect our applications to our databases.

This one application works just fine inside visual studio when in either "Release Mode" or "Debug Mode", but once you go and install the app via the .msi file, we get this error:

> "The type initializer for 'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration' threw an
>   exception"

Usually when we get this error it's because a mapping is wrong or maybe the connection string, but this isn't the case here. Like I mentioned above, the project works just fine in visual studio, but not the installed version. The .dlls are the same versions in all instances.

This is really throwing me through a loop and I'm hoping someone out there has any ideas or has experienced this issue before.

Thanks and let me know if you need any data from my end.

Update:

Actually was able to run by attaching to the process (I installed a debug version). So I was able to see an inner exception:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)"  string.

We are using NHibernate and Crystal reports for vs2010 in our app and there are two log4net references in the setup project. Both are v1.2.10 but both have diff public key tokens.

I believe I solved this.

Like I mentioned the project will run in visual studio but not when it's installed. So I noticed this morning that there were two "log4net.dll" objects in my detected dependancies folder. Both log4net.dlls were the same version "1.2.10", but both were using different public key tokens. This seemed very odd to me. I had the same version but both had different encryption keys.

Anyways I excluded one of the two dlls and I installed the project again, and now it is running. I hope nothing is affected by this. So it isn't perfectly solved, but for right now it works and that's what I needed.

The two keys for reference were:
692FBEA5521E1304
1B44E1D426115821

Thanks to NOtherDev and Shane Coutrille for your input. I guess I won't make this an answer to the question since this isn't the ideal solution.

Comment: Are you sure all dependencies are there? Like NHibernate and Iesi.Collections? Can you log the InnerException, too?

Comment: Yeah I just got the inner exception, it was a log4net issue. Still unsure of how to fix it.

Comment: I see in other post on stack that many people are having an issue with this. I'm looking through those posts at the moment now that I know it may be log4net that's giving me a headache.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but was able to resolve it by following steps :
* Removing all the references of the Nhibernate and fluent NHibernate and iesiCollection etc.
* Add a new reference of FluentNHibernate from NuGate in Visual studio 2012, it will add automatically all its dependencies like NHibernate etc.
* This way the assemblies will not be conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

The public key was changed between 1.2.9 and 1.2.10 (and in fact 1.2.11 has TWO keys..)  Are you sure you don't have a 1.2.9 and a 1.2.10?  If they are both .10 then it's possible someone hand built a 1.2.10 using the old key for comparability reasons.

The only solution we've found to this problem is to find versions of the 3rd party tools that agree on which public key version of log4net to use.  So far we've only had this problem with Windsor 3 (which appears to use 1.2.11 new public key) but I expect this problem to become common as we move through a period where some projects upgrade to 1.2.11 (new key) and others are still using 1.2.9 or 1.2.10 or 1.2.11 old key.

Comment: yeah I'm 100% sure i'm looking at the setup project right now. I want it to be the case where i have 2 versions, but both are the same. We have NHibernate v2.1.2.4000 which is using log4net v1.2.10 and CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Prompting and it's using log4net v1.2.10. Both log4net's are in the setup project one is in GAC the other in a library folder we have set up. Both have different public key tokens.

Comment: oh and my condolences on having to use Crystal ;)